# Displaying a column Of Sql in JTextArea in NetBeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, wamp

I am trying to make a chat messenger in NetBeans with a Java front end and MySQL in WAMP and I'm stuck at a point where I want to display the registered users in a `jTextArea` as shown:

[image: chat messenger frame]

Also, I want to add that my database is connected to the application.

this my code for displaying  although I am not getting any error my nothing is displayed either

```
try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306","root",""); 
  String abc = "select user from ch.login"; 
  pst = conn.prepareStatement(abc); 
  rs= pst.executeQuery(abc); 
  chat cc=new chat(); 
  cc.jTextArea2.setText(abc);
}catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, this is QA forum not blog FYI. At current stage your question cannot be answered because you haven't asked answerable question. Please post what is the issue in question itself don't post external links. Please read Help Center to know how to ask good question.

Comment: what you are asking is unclear. If you want to connect to mysql then learn about `JDBC`.

Comment: Satya ...... my application is connected to mysql in wamp now my query is how to get list of registered users in jtextarea ..... and Simze what is FYI ?

Comment: You are not using resultSet `rs` in a proper way. First seach for any jdbc-mysql example then try it yourself. You can find one example [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database)

Comment: thank you @m.yadav . But I am still confused Where am i getting wrong please be specific what is my logical error .

Answer (score 0):

You have to first check that do you have any value in resultSet using `rs.next()` then fetch the data from resultSet. Since you are selecting only one column `rs.getString(1)` where 1 is index of column.

```
try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306","root",""); 
  String abc = "select user from ch.login"; 
  pst = conn.prepareStatement(abc); 
  rs= pst.executeQuery(abc); 
  if(rs.next()){ // you can use while loop if you have more then one row in database
    chat cc=new chat(); 
    cc.jTextArea2.setText(rs.getString(1));
  }
}catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
}
```

Again I would suggest you to first create one or two example program for JDBC with MySQL before writing your own logic.